# How to make my left side menu bar to show and hide on click with changing icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, django-templates

Hello i know this question is being asked many times, i tried many of the solutions but it dint work for me. Hence i thought of posting this question for some help.
I have an django applications which have some html templates done with the help of **bootstrap**. Now i want one of div to completely hide (**when it is hidden an icon should be appearing in place of sidebar**) and show left side menu bar on-click of icon. 
Here is my html file

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>**</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/dashboard.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <link href="{% static 'style.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
   
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="{% static "bootstrap/css/logo4.png" %}" alt="MPOWER" style="margin-top:-5%;"/></a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {% if user.is_authenticated %}

        {{ user.first_name }}
       {{ request.user.username }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out\"></span>Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" >
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" id="mobile-menu">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
<li><a href="#"><span id="menu-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span></a></li>
        <li><span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Dashboardsssss</span></li>     
  {% for Dashboard in dashboards %}
<li><a href="{{ Dashboard.d_url }}" target="iframe_a">{{ Dashboard.d_name }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          
        </div>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" style="height:600px; margin-top:4%;">


<iframe width="100%"  height="95%" name="iframe_a" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>


   </div>

</div>



<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>

  <script src="{% static 'index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}



</body>
</html
```

in above html page i want  this div to be showed and hidden on each click and it should have an icon on the same menu bar for doing this.
note: icon should be visible in all time.
please help me to do this functionality.
thanks in advance.
and css looks like

```html
#main_header .panel_btn {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 15px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: rgb(200,200,200);
 z-index: 5;
}

#main_header .panel_btn .line {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 background: rgb(80,80,80);
}
#main_header .panel_btn .line:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}


.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
  
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    
          }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content

 */
```

Comment: Snippets are meant to have HTML and CSS joined, not seperate.

Comment: @Blake i do have linked my css to html using link rel

Comment: No, I mean in your question, you need to have your CSS and HTML in your snippet. I'll edit your post..

Comment: @Blake, yup i got it,  now how to get the functionality what i need.

Comment: what are the '{' for in your HTML? Is it for bootstrap code?

Comment: @Blake no its django code.. but now worries for django its just used to display some dashboards.

Comment: ok, hahah, not familiar in django

Comment: @Blake that’s okay can you please suggest me how to achieve my problem..

Comment: quick question, in your actual code, do you end it with '</html>', as in your question you have '</html'

Comment: @Blake yup i do end with </html> closing tag

Comment: sorry, i can't really do anything because most of your code is... well... like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e45wpzL9/).

Comment: @Blake, forget about django i will resolve it.please can u help in html css and javascript

Comment: @Blake, do u want me post javascript and css what i have done till now

Comment: Sorry, I try and help when I can, but I'm just a beginner too. Sorry.

Comment: Best option is to just google it or go on youtube..

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need the collapsed navbar. There is the information about it: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar